Adding auto regression n_lags- seems to remove any predictions
I feel like this is extremely basic. The data set is just gold stock market prices- ds/datetime and closing price/y. Here is the code:
m2 = NeuralProphet(drop_missing= True , growth= 'discontinuous', n_lags=50)
m2.set_plotting_backend("plotly-static")
metrics = m2.fit(basicdf, freq= 'H')
#future = m2.make_future_dataframe(basicdf, periods=50, n_historic_predictions=True)
forecast = m2.predict(future) 

Without n_lags the models works and predicts well. When i add autoregression i get 1 of 2 errors:
if len(data) != len(index):
--> 576         raise ValueError(
    577             "Length of values "
    578             f"({len(data)}) "

ValueError: Length of values (4624) does not match length of index (4601)

or
the prediction works but all the yhat1 values are NaN.
Any ideas: the model should be smart enough to know the first few values are lagged, also why would it not predict anything when the n_lag is small??? if i remove n_lag parameter it works as expected.
Im using data from yahoo :
mgc_data = yf.download('MGC=F', period='1y', interval='1h')
